# RSA in digital certificate

Tags: cryptography, certificate, rsa

In a digital certificate issued to a domain, using an RSA cipher, I would like to find the prime number used in the encryption. In firefox you get the public key size and the public exponent e used in RSA. Is it then possible to find the modulus?

I have been told it is possible to find all the components of the RSA public key in the certificate.

Comment: "All the RSA public key components" are in the certificate. The public key **is** the modulus and public exponent. The primes (not prime) are private and revealing them would render the key compromised and useless.

Comment: I don't get this question as Firefox does show the modulus value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does show the modulus.  It shows it in hexadecimal, though, because it's a really big number and most people don't want it as a number.

If you click in the box it expands to the full text, then with some careful mousing you can select from the beginning to the end (the other way around seems to close the box).

[image]

The current stackoverflow.com modulus is `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`.

Throwing that at a big number converter, such as https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php, and converting hex to decimal, gives `28545667559270722536328739022786592253819358506259770100402101435896071697903628977420219545326987103272186552420452973169159370835343752815436439028214107596377595573672473455033151197271343902899123866538498523276704745196410920898299228024215266960005847032342465925829796610222069401784309268841026345683372697803322805210779147292332915465882324168923726887448041529546541821503314352568777720204912372696110914871608165395895300061714914624066001642195838915022687649853436371063685464728624168828232056605406696894580332490208286479538969275877424497344433351991392941870270197646347642298881819314989427521779`